# Do sideloaded iOS apps get permissions without asking?

Tags: ios, applications, permission

Apple allows anyone with the source code of an app to sideload it onto their iOS device using Xcode.

If I sideload an app onto my iOS device, will it have access to information that a normal app would ask for(ex:location, contacts, photos)? Will it still ask for permission to use my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will still ask for permission. Just as if you had downloaded it from the store, it will fail to access your camera, contacts, notifications unless you grant permission.

This is important for developers, because it helps ensure that they catch any bugs where they don't ask when they are testing on their devices.  Apps loaded from Xcode follow the same rules in this regard as apps from the App Store.